# How to convert the month name in english text in Datetime to arabic text in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a date which is displayed as 12 May 2013. I am using the format "dd MMMM yyyy". I want to display the month text i.e May in arabic text. Is there any way? Also, Is there a way to convert the english numbers to arabic numbers in the datetime?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using C# programming language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried using an Arabic [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx)?

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Now;
var dateString = dateTime.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ar"));
```

*ar* is the [ISO 639 two-letter language code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes). You can also specify a subculture such as *ar-EG* for *Arabic (Egypt)*.

Comment: Something to mention, is that there "neutral" cultures, e.g. (en, fr, ar...etc), you can't use them directly. You should provide the sub culture like "ar-IQ" or "en-GB"...etc.

Comment: You are a life saver that's what you are, because there is a big difference between

lblSelectedMonth.Text = selectedDate.ToString("MMMM", new CultureInfo("ar-EG"));

And

lblSelectedMonth.Text = selectedDate.ToString("MMMM", new CultureInfo("ar"));